# To trim particular value in a column

Tags: regex, select, conditional-statements, oracle12c, regexp-replace

I have a regular expression select statement like below :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(nvl(l.text_1, l.text),'^'||21810||'=|\|'
                                    ||21810||'=', '|'||21810||'='||'B1') 
                                    FROM table_1 1
```

This checks the value of texts and add's B1 if the text has 21810

eg: If my text is `21614=C1||21810=C2`

what it does is : `21614=C1|||||||21810=B1C2`

But I want this to remove this C1 and C2 which is always followed by a '=' and just add B1 after '=' in 21810

```
 21614=|||||||21810=B1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two-step replacement:

1. Remove values after `=` and before `|`:
   Replace `[^=|]+(\||$)` with `\1`. See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/O5yqaL/1/).
2. Next, add `B1`:
   `(^|\|)21810=` with `\121810=B1`.
   See [this regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/KTVWO6/3/).